# Gridgain as high speed data storage

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I deployed Gridgain server in Kubernets with native persistence enabled. Data read speed in expected level. Also it use as primary data storage. So data should not be lost. I faced some issues several times and solution given as clean work directory.

Can I know is Gridgain suitable for primary database?

Comment: GridGain has provided several backup options for extended versions (EE and UE) in the form of snapshots and data replication. You can also implement your own replication to remote storage using Kafka for example. However, I don't think clearing the working directory is the solution to your problems. This is the easiest way to get a clean cluster. Can you share a link where it was suggested? What problems did you have?

Comment: Yes cleaning is not a solution, because we have sensitive application data. I get this cleaning suggestion few months ago.  Anyway my question is Gridgain is suitable option for primary database like mysql, mongo db, HBase, Cacandra etc.